# JavaScript: Last setInterval lasts longer then expected

Tags: javascript

I asked for help before on how to fix something with my javascript code, I have that fixed now however is there a problem with my code? Because the last array stays on for longer than 1 second, it stays on for like 5 seconds. Is this because I'm resetting the array or is this normal in Javascript?

```
function Background()
{
    var Backgrounds = [
        '#333', '#777', '#999', '#CCC'
    ],
    Max_Backgrounds = Backgrounds.length, 
    Background_Stage = -1;// Yes, it's meant to be -1 so when background_stage++; is called it will make it 0 thus start at the beginning of the array.
    setInterval(function() { 
        if(Background_Stage >= Max_Backgrounds) Background_Stage = -1;
            $('body').css('background', Backgrounds[Background_Stage++]); 
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Why do you set `Background_Stage` to -1 instead of 0? Also: you reset it *instead* of switching the background.

Comment: Side note: Javascript is **not** Java.

Comment: @ Joachim Sauer I set it to -1 because 0 is the starting array number and Background_Stage++; makes it 0 over wise it would be 1.

Comment: @ Ingo Bürk I know was a typo.

Comment: I've added the updated code and still lasts more than 5 seconds.

Comment: As they said before, check the Background_Stage initialization value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you are not changing the background in the last iteration, which is why it lingers for longer than the others, this should keep it consistent

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/uRSC5/

```
function background() {
    var backgrounds = [
        /*"./../../Styles/Callum_Project1/Images/Background_1",
        "./../../Styles/Callum_Project1/Images/Background_2",
        "./../../Styles/Callum_Project1/Images/Background_3"*/
        '#333', '#777', '#999', '#CCC'
    ];

    var count = backgrounds.length;
    var i = 0;

    setInterval(function() { 
        $('body').css('background', backgrounds[i++]); 
        if(i >= count) i = 0;
    }, 1000);
}

$(background);
```

Comment: Also the `Background_Stage > Max_Backgrounds` check is flawed, when that occured it's already too late.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not doing the -1 initialization and use rather the module. i.e. `3 % 2 == 1` which yields the remainder of a division.

http://jsfiddle.net/KtsHa/1/

```
(function Background () {
    var Backgrounds = [
        '#333', '#777', '#999', '#CCC'
    ],
    Max_Backgrounds = Backgrounds.length, 
    Background_Stage = 0,
    changeBackground = function () {
        $('body').css('background', Backgrounds[Background_Stage]); 
        Background_Stage = (Background_Stage + 1) % Max_Backgrounds;                
    };
    changeBackground(); // Remove this line if what you intend is to wait one second before the first change
    setInterval(changeBackground, 1000);
}());
```

Also, setInterval is known to drift, so I'd rather use setTimeout and do it again 1 second later:
http://jsfiddle.net/KtsHa/2/

```
(function () {
    var Backgrounds = [
        '#333', '#777', '#999', '#CCC'
    ],
    Max_Backgrounds = Backgrounds.length, 
    Background_Stage = 0,
    changeBackground = function () {
        $('body').css('background', Backgrounds[Background_Stage]); 
        Background_Stage = (Background_Stage + 1) % Max_Backgrounds;
        setTimeout(changeBackground, 1000);
    };
    changeBackground();
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').css('background', Backgrounds[Background_Stage++]);
```

is equivalent to

```
$('body').css('background', Backgrounds[Background_Stage]);
Background_Stage = Background_Stage + 1;
```

Each time around the loop, the background is getting set to undefined.  If you want to have your variable increment **before** being accessed you would need to use

```
$('body').css('background', Backgrounds[++Background_Stage]);
```

full example (if condition was also modified):

```
function Background()
{
    var Backgrounds = [
        '#333', '#777', '#999', '#CCC'
    ],
    Max_Backgrounds = Backgrounds.length, 
    Background_Stage = -1;// Yes, it's meant to be -1 so when background_stage++; is called it will make it 0 thus start at the beginning of the array.
    setInterval(function() { 
        if(Background_Stage >= Max_Backgrounds - 1) Background_Stage = -1;
            $('body').css('background', Backgrounds[++Background_Stage]); 
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: `Backgrounds[Background_Stage++]` is correct if you initialize to `0` as opposed to the more confusing `-1`, as in `for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)`

Comment: I agree, but I thought it was the order of operations that was tripping up @Callum.  I wanted to provide an explanation on why he was having an issue, rather than just refactor the code.

Comment: good point, agreed, I figured in my last edit I'd just refactor it to something a bit more idiomatic